# Specifying ordering of backref / RelatedManager in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-related-manager

I currently have two Models:

```
class Blog(Model):
  ...

class Entry(Model):
   blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
   capture_dt = models.DateTimeField()
```

If I want `blog.entry_set` to be ordered by `capture_dt`, it seems like the best way to get this is adding a `Meta` class to the `Entry` model with ordering set to `ordering = ('capture_dt', )`.

Unfortunately this now changes the global sorting behavior of `Entry` as opposed to just how I sort when accessing it from the `Blog` model. Is there a way to set the ordering behavior on a backref per backref basis?

FWIW, SQLAlchemy supports this when declaring the relationship:

```
class Blog(Base):
    ...
    entry_set = relationship("Entry", order_by="Entry.capture_dt")
```